# Scala's either with tuple as Right

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Suppose I have following code:

```
val either: Either[String, (Int, Int)] = Right((1,2))
for {
  (a, b) <- either.right
} yield a + b
```

When I evaluate it in REPL I get

> :13: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected
>   type;  found   : (T1, T2)  required:
>   scala.util.Either[Nothing,(Double, Double)]
>                 (a, b) <- a.right
>                 ^ :14: error: not found: value a
>                 } yield a + b
>                         ^

Why do I have such error? Can't I pattern match on tuple from Either's Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue seems to be a scala bug https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7222. Converting the for comprehension to flatMap/map notation seems to work.

```
val either: Either[String, (Int, Int)] = Right((1, 2))
either.right.map {
  case (a, b) =>
    a + b
}

either: Either[String,(Int, Int)] = Right((1,2))
res0: Serializable with Product with scala.util.Either[String,Int] = Right(3)
```

Comment: I'm using scala 2.10.3.  Also why does it have such a strange type: `Serializable with Product with scala.util.Either[String,Int]`? Why not just `scala.util.Either[String,Int]`